# bind9 4th level subdomain CNAME record doesn't work

Tags: dns, bind

I met strange issue

Record like

stage.proj2 IN CNAME www.example.com.

Doesn't work. I know this record is generally correct. 
The server wasn't configured by me, I never use such kind of records.
Something in bind 9 configuration?

Comment: What does not work? Provide the true name involved and if you have the zonefile test yourself with `named-checkzone`

Comment: named-checkzone shows ok. stage-proj2.mydom.com works perfectly. stage.proj.mydom.com doesn't work (only in local network). Serial was increased.

Comment: Is `mydom.com` really the domain name we are speaking about it, or is that some obfuscation of yours? Also in your question you had `stage.proj2` and now you are speaking about `stage-proj2` and `stage.proj`. Please edit your question to be clearer and with full details without obfuscation.

Comment: There are stage.proj2 and stage-proj2. First doesn't work, send work. Domain is real.

Answer (score 0):

Use online tools for diagnostics, here is the result with DNSviz:

- http://dnsviz.net/d/stage.proj2.mydom.com/WnDDVA/dnssec/ for `stage.proj2.mydom.com`
- http://dnsviz.net/d/stage-proj2.mydom.com/WnDDYg/dnssec/ for `stage-proj2.mydom.com`

Note that they both show errors and warnings. You have in fact of mismatch for the list of authoritative nameservers on your domain, either because of a misconfiguration, or a recent change:
`.com`authoritative nameservers list for your zone `mydom.com`, nameservers `buy.internettraffic.com.` and `buy.internettraffic.com.` as authoritative but when you query them for your zone, they reply instead that `ns1.uniregistrymarket.link.` and `ns2.uniregistrymarket.link.` are authoritative for your zone. You should first work to remove this discrepancy.

Now let us do a resolution by hand, as a cold resolver would do, for `stage-proj2.mydom.com`:

1. `dig @a.root-servers.net stage-proj2.mydom.com A` replies, as expected, with:

   ```
   ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
   com.                    172800 IN NS e.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800 IN NS b.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800 IN NS j.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800 IN NS m.gtld-servers.net.
   [...]
   ```
2. `dig @e.gtld-servers.net. stage-proj2.mydom.com A` replies, as expected, with:

   ```
   ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
   mydom.com.              172800 IN NS buy.internettraffic.com.
   mydom.com.              172800 IN NS sell.internettraffic.com.
   ```
3. `dig @buy.internettraffic.com. stage-proj2.mydom.com A` and `dig @sell.internettraffic.com. stage-proj2.mydom.com A` both reply as expected with:

   ```
   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
   stage-proj2.mydom.com.  300 IN A 69.172.201.153
   ```

   There are no CNAME records here.
4. If we test with the other name instead, the result are the same, `stage.proj2` resolves to the same IP address, in the same way.

So in short I see no problem in fact for both `stage-proj2` and `stage.proj2` in your zone. Did you remoe the CNAME records?

You will need to specify more your problems: what command did you use and what results did you get (specific error message) and what did you expect instead.